# images with different size at the center of the cards in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have the following HTML code to put a list of organization's logos and links inside card.

Whenever I add a logo, card size change in according to logo size and image not centered inside card.

I have used `class = mx-auto` and `class = card-block` but didnt work out.

```html
<section class="site-section" id="section-blog">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
                            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
                                <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
                                    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png"
                                        alt="" class="mx-auto">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
                                <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
                                    <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt=""
                                        class="card-img">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
                                <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
                                    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png"
                                        alt="" class="card-img">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
                                <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
                                    <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt=""
                                        class="card-img">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </section>
```

Comment: In my browser, everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and everything seems to be working, except the first card element and its **image**. The image should have a class of `card-img`. Be sure to check the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wkh7ru1o/18/). Maybe the issue is in the **bootstrap link** you are using